Does conditioning commute with sums?
Warning the below question is (necessarily, due to my naivete) phrased imprecisely.
I have two random variables $X_0, X_1$, and two events $E_0, E_1$. I know that the conditional random variables $X_0\mid E_0$ and $X_1\mid E_1$ are well-defined, and know how to work with them.
I'm interested if there is some "standard" event $E_+$ such that one has
$$\tag{1}
(X_0+X_1)\mid E_+ = X_0\mid E_0+X_1\mid E_1
$$
Essentially, I want conditioning on $E$ to "commute" with the sum.
I'm fine with whatever niceness assumptions are required on $X_0, X_1, E_0, E_1$. I don't know the precise notion of equality I want for (1), but I expect something like in distribution.
So, is there some definition of event $E_+$, depending on $E_0$ and $E_1$, such that Eq. (1) holds (perhaps only under suitable independence assumptions)? If so, what is $E_+$, and what are the independence assumptions?
Naively, does conditioning commute with sums?

The expression $X_0\mid E_0+X_1\mid E_1$ is making me a little uncomfortable, I'm not convinced this sum is actually well defined or useful:  Consider the case where $E_0$ is the event that a coin lands on tails and $X_0$ is an indicator variable for the same, and $E_1$ and $X_1$ are similar for the same coin landing heads.  Clearly, $X_0 + X_1 = 1$, $X_0\mid E_0 = 1$, and $X_1\mid E_1$, which would make $X_0\mid E_0+X_1\mid E_1$ be $2$, I guess?  I'm not sure how to interpret that but it seems bad.

Maybe this will help --- I have some collection $(X_0, X_2, \dots, X_n)$ of independent random variables. Each event $E_i = {|X_i| \leq c_i}$ is the event that one of the (independent) $X_i$ is suitably bounded. In this case $X_0\mid E_0 + X_1\mid E_1$ seems to be fine, perhaps because each pair $(X_i, E_i)$ (by any reasonable definition) does not depend on randomness used to define any other pair.

Even in this case though, it's not clear to me what the event $E_+$ is supposed to look like, or if it can be reasonably be defined.

Under the (very strong) independence conditions that $X_0 | E_0$ is independent of $E_1$ and $X_1 | E_1$ is independent of $E_0$, we have
$$
(X_0 + X_1) \mid (E_0 \cap E_1) = X_0 \mid (E_0 \cap E_1) + X_1 \mid (E_0 \cap E_1) = X_0 \mid E_0 + X_1 \mid E_1
$$

Notation: Given a random variable $X$, I use $\mathcal X$ to denote it’s induced $\sigma$-algebra.
There may be some slight confusion with how the conditional random variables $X_0 | E_0$, $X_1 | E_1$ are defined. Formally, random variables are just functions from a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ to the real numbers.
When one writes $X_0| E_0$, what one really means is that we consider the same function $X_0$, but this time under the new probability measure $\mathbb P_{|E_0}$ given by
$$\mathbb P_{|E_0} (E) := \frac{\mathbb P(E \cap E_0)}{\mathbb P(E)}.$$
Thus your question is more or less, given $X_0, X_1, E_0, E_1$, is there always an $E_+$ such that $\mathbb P_{|E_+} = \mathbb P_{|E_0}$ on all events $E \in \mathcal X_0$ and $\mathbb P_{E_+} = \mathbb P_{E_1}$ on all events $F \in \mathcal X_1$?
As mentioned, this is generally not possible. Also as mentioned, under some strong assumptions (say independence of $X_0$ and $X_1$, and $E_i \in \mathcal X_i$ for each $i$) we can actually take $E_+ := E_0 \cap E_1$.
One can relax this to conditional independence given an auxiliary event $A$, in which case we can take $E_+ := A \cap E_0 \cap E_1$.
For an example in which it is not possible to find such an event, take three dice rolls in sequence $D_1, D_2, D_3$, where $D_1$ has $n$ sides, and $D_i$ has $D_{i-1}$ sides but is otherwise independent of $D_{i-1}$. Then set $X := D_1 + D_3$, $Y := D_2 + D_3$.
